# Como rodar server com loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, loopback

Tenho acesso a um projeto *backend* e gostaria de saber como faço para **rodar** esse projeto. Ele utiliza `loopback` e ao ler a [documentação](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/server.js.html) do `loopback`, na **instrução 4** diz:

> Start the web server.

Qual **comando** deveria usar no **Ubuntu** para começar esse `webserver` com o `loopback`?

Após rodar o comando `npm install -g loopback-cli`e tentar rodar o sistema com `node .` ou `node server.js` aparece esse **ERRO** no terminal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `node server.js` corre o ficheiro, ou queres saber como o ter autónomo para se auto iniciar quando tiver problemas ou o servidor fizer reboot?

Comment: Vê se isto aqui http://loopback.io/getting-started/ e isto https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Running-and-debugging-apps.html ajuda

Comment: @Sergio quando tento `node server.js` aparece a mensagem: _modulos 'loopback' não encontrados_

Comment: Podes colocar o erro na pergunta?

Comment: @Tmc eu instalei o loopback como fala no primeiro link e tentei rodar utilizando o `node .` porém diz que o _módulo 'loopback' não foi encontrados_. Sabe o que pode ser? E eu rodei o comando `npm install -g loopback-cli`

Comment: @Sergio sim, um instante!

Comment: @Sergio pergunta editada!

Comment: Tens esse pacote no `package.json`? Se não faz `npm install --save loopback`. Se tens faz `npm install`.

Comment: @Tmc eu editei a pergunta postando o erro.

Comment: @Sergio eu precisava ter rodado o `npm install` mesmo! Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: @Tmc funcionou quando li essa perguntar que você mandou, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo @Sergio nos comentários, basta executar o seguinte comando:

```
npm install
```

> Pode ver mais informações no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145486/strongloop-loopback-error-cannot-find-module-on-finished).

Answer (score 0):

O loopback é uma aplicação em node que utiliza de packages como dependências sendo os mesmos controlados via npm. Sendo assim, a aplicação precisa de suas dependências para ser inicializada.

Para instalar as dependências de uma aplicação em NodeJS, você pode executar o comando `npm install`, que irá instalar todas as dependências da aplicação.
Ou em caso de produção, recomendo o `npm install --production`, o que evita a instalação de packages necessários apenas para dev.

Após executar a instalação das dependências, você pode executar a aplicação via `node .` ou `npm start`.

Recomendo a utilização do `npm start` em caso de dev., pois o mesmo pode ter scripts extras para execução correta do mesmo (Você pode analizar isso olhando para `package.json`, na sessão scripts -> start.